# How to fetch data after the app is restarted in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i am developing an app for a shop and the bill number should be saved if the app is terminated and the number should be fetched on restarting the app. please help me. if someone could point me at the right direction that would be so much helpful.

Comment: just google for `android store data permanently`. You will need ~12 seconds to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences should do the job. They store information in a key-value pair even when the device is turned off or restarted, and of course when the app is closed out of.

Here's a link to the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Here's a useful tutorial that I learnt best from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJEFZ6EOM9o

Hope it helps :)